# Pure cloths become impure if comes contact with one another?

Tags: halal-haram, taharah

If i keep a pure cloth with a impure cloth in my wardrobe. .then the pure cloth becomes impure?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's according to the state of the impurity;

•If it's **dry** , then impurity doesn't transfer, so pure clothes remain pure

•If it's **wet** , impurity transfers, and pure clothes becomes impure by touching **wet** impure clothes

For more info:
[Dry impurity does not pass to the one who touched it](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111904/dry-impurity-does-not-pass-to-the-one-who-touches-it)